# How to load a image from directory using flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to click on a button and then choose a image to load (browsing directories) and use it as background.

Is that possible using flash and actionscript 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Loader class to do this:

```
function LoadImage(imageURL:String) {
    var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded); // event listener which is fired when loading is complete
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(imageURL));
}

function ImageLoaded(e:Event) {
    e.target.loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded);
    this.addChild(e.target.loader.content); // loaded content is stored in e.target.loader.content variable
}
```

But, if you want to load image from local directory you can use FileReference class to do that, read the documentation for more details.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Comment: That loads from a url correct? I want to load it from local directory and I want to choose the image.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer, you can use FileReference class to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, use Loader class...
[read here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) for how to use it.

Comment: but how can I choose (browsing in directories) the image to be loaded?

Comment: That loads from a url correct? I want to load it from local directory and I want to choose the image.

Comment: You should probably implement a file explorer for browsing in directories, or look for one on the Internet. It could lead you some security issues though, since flash isn't much allowed to work outside a browser's context.